# How to run C++ program that use PDCurses on other computers?

Tags: c++, dll, portability, pdcurses

I've recently started using PDCurses in a C++ game I'm working on. When I compile the program on my own machine (windows) and run the .exe, everything works as it should.

When I take that .exe onto a different computer that doesn't have PDCurses and I try to run it, I get an error about a missing pdcurses.dll file.

After doing a bit of research online, I found out that including the .dll file along with the .exe should make it run but it didn't work for me.

This is how I compiled the program using MinGW: `g++ game.cpp -o game -lpdcurses`

So my question is, how do I make this program run on computers that don't have PDCurses setup, and also, is there a way to do this by combining the .exe with whatever additional file(s) the system needs to run the program? I've also read that you can do some sort of static linking but so far I've been unable to find a way to do this.

Thanks in advance for the help.

NOTE: In case it matters, I setup PDCurses following this tutorial: http://comptb.cects.com/1848-adding-pdcurses-to-mingw
Not sure if that was the best way to do it but I'm able to compile and run C++ code that uses pdcurses on my computer fine.

---

Sorry for not posting the exact messages. Here they are:

The first one I got when I didn't include the pdcurses.dll file along with the executable said :

*The program can't start because pdcurses.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.*

The second one I got after I included the pdcurses.dll:

*The program can't start because libcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.*

Comment: What does *doesn't work* mean? What exact error messages do you get?

Comment: By "work" I mean that it doesn't run at all. I just give me the error about the missing pdcurses.dll

Comment: And what happens if you copy the `pdcurses.dll` into the same folder as the `game.exe` file? Then it should work.

Comment: When I tried doing that, it didn't give me the error about pdcurses.dll anymore but it did give me a different error about a different missing .dll file. Do you know of I way I would compile the program and link it with the.dll at the same time?

Comment: No, I don't know how to do that, but now there is enough information for others to solve this problem. :)

Comment: You just need to put "different missing .dll" into the app directory too. Probably. Of course, if you actually knew what that dll was (it is clearly named in the error dialog which you merely need to read) then we might be able to give you better help.

Comment: You can simple use the ghost++ configuration to disable the usage of pdcurses. the first few lines of the cfg file. Doing that it will act just line any normal console applications

Comment: meant to say "Like" on the above reply. Another way it for you to compile it using visual studio instead, I have done it in both ways and it works just fine with VS no dependencies at all for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include all the dynamic libraries you linked with. Be careful of licensing, although IIRC there's not much that will bite you with MinGW.

There should be a 'ldd' command if you have the MinGW shell. Try running it on game.exe and it will tell you what libraries you need to run your program. You need to include them all with the exe.

If you want to try and remove the dependency nightmare you can use the static linking (-static) option to your gcc link command. You may not be able to actually do that if you don't have the static versions of your libraries installed. This has other implications - your exe will be bigger and the OS's shared shared page code will not work because it can't tell what parts (DLL code) you are sharing with other apps. In effect, your application will use more memory as a result, although it may be insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to get the sources to PDCurses and compile it as a static library.  That way you don't have to get involved in the DLL Hell.

Compile it as a C library instead of a C++ library and you should be good to go.